# Can I have a bootable pendrive while having /home and /usr on the laptop hdd?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, usb-drive

I currently have Win10 + Ubuntu on my laptop, both boot from HDD through grub. The problem is if I'm to reinstall Windows it wipes grub and I'd have to reinstall Ubuntu as well. I want to avoid it by getting Ubuntu boot from pendrive while its `/home` and `/usr` parts are to remain on the HDD thus I wouldn't need grub and will just plug in the pendrive when I need Ubuntu.

Would it suffice to just mount `/boot` partition to pendrive and everything else (`/`, `/home`, `/usr` etc.) to hard drive upon installation or some other steps are required to get the setup to work?

Comment: Windows wipe of GRUB does not require you to reinstall Ubuntu. You simply need to run grub-install or boot-repair from your LiveUSB.

Comment: Don't make question which is based on a wrong guess. Ask your central question (which here it was if you need to reinstall ubuntu after windows installation)